# Extracting parts of a URL from a string

Tags: php

I have a URL/string

```
localhost/showquestion.php?subtopic=1&question=0&count=2
```

and I want to extract the variables like this:

```
    $subtopic=1;//could be 100000 
    $question=0;//could be anything
    $count=2;
```

from this URL.

I use this to get the URL:

```
$url= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

I tried to take integers by using the function

```
$int = (int)filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

How can I extract the variables from the URL?

Comment: Aren't they already in `$_GET`, or did I mis-understand the question?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php if it isn't the URL of your page, or simply use $_GET

Comment: yup they use to be $_GET.. i use to send these values via form. but now the situation is change, i hv to receive the values from url.

Comment: thanks man for revision @george Cummins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user php's [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function. Does exactly what you want.

```
parse_str(
  parse_url("localhost/showquestion.php?subtopic=1&question=0&count=2",
            PHP_URL_QUERY));
```

Comment: no output but you can use $subtopic and $count in your script as though they where assigned.

Comment: directly after this if you `echo $subtopic;` it would print 1

Comment: be careful that this isn't used maliciously to change other variables in your code.

Comment: thanks man the code works... don't know y ppl downrated this question

Answer (score 3):

Just read from the `$_GET` global:

```
$subtopic = isset($_GET['subtopic']) ? $_GET['subtopic'] : null;
```

Comment: yeah i know Sir how this $_GET works.  here consider i am taking data from some website. i got the URL as string. now i want to extract these variables. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$_GET['subtopic'];
$_GET['question'];
$_GET['count'];
```

Comment: sir, i know this $_GET variable. i just want to extract data from string.

Comment: @user2083529 can you kindly explain please, why bother to get a string first and then get variables from it, if you have your vars *already?*

Answer (score 0):

Just use $_REQUEST['subtopic'] or $_GET['subtopic'] or whichever url var you want.